# Data is not displayed in the tableedit

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating an editable table with php and AJAX, I have done everything but it does not print the data in the table, I do not know why, because it does not give me any error, I do not know if I have something wrong in the code, I clarify that in the part of SCRIPT.js where I make the edit script, things are missing, can you give me a hand?

INDEX

```
 <table id="personal" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th >Incidencia
  </th>
  <th >Departamento
  </th>
  <th >Usuario
  </th>
  <th >Estado
  </th>
  <th >Fecha de apertura
  </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

datos.php

```
<?php


include('dbconect.php');

$column = array("incidencia", "nom_dep", "usuario", "estado","fecha_inicio");

$query = "SELECT incidencia.*, usuarios.usuario, departamento.nom_dep,estado.estado FROM incidencia";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
 INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = incidencia.usuario"%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR INNER JOIN departamento ON departamento.cod = incidencia.nom_dep LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR INNER JOIN estado ON estado.id = incidencia.estado LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY incidencia asc ';
}
$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $conexion->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $conexion->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row['incidencia'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['nom_dep'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['usuario'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['estado'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['fecha_inicio'];
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($conexion)
{
 $query = "SELECT incidencia.*, usuarios.usuario, departamento.nom_dep,estado.estado FROM incidencia INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = incidencia.usuario INNER JOIN departamento ON departamento.cod = incidencia.nom_dep INNER JOIN estado ON estado.id = incidencia.estado";
 $statement = $conexion->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 'draw'   => intval($_POST['draw']),
 'recordsTotal' => count_all_data($conexion),
 'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
 'data'   => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

SCRIPT.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataTable = $('#personal').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [],
        "ajax": {
            url: "datos.php",
            type: "POST",
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "incidencia" },
            { "data": "nom_dep" },
            { "data": "usuario" },
            { "data": "estado" },
            { "data": "fecha_inicio" }
        ]


    });

    $('#personal').on('draw.dt', function() {
        $('#personal').Tabledit({
            url: 'edicion.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, 'incidencia'],
                editable: [
                    [1, 'nom_dep'],
                    [2, 'usuario'],
                    [3, 'estado'],
                    [4, 'fecha_inicio']
                ]
            },
            restoreButton: false,
            onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.action == 'delete') {
                    $('#' + data.idp).remove();
                    $('#personal').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `id` of the table you use to instantiate the DataTable is incorrect. You use `$('#personal')` but the table `id` is `tablaUsuarios` in HMTL you provided.

Should you be using `$('#tablaUsuarios')` when selecting the table in your jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, it was another table from another project, I have already corrected and put the correct one.

Comment: Ah no problem. Are you getting any data back in the ajax response?